# Why am i getting an UnboundLocalError in this list comprehension problem?

Tags: python, iterator, list-comprehension

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
print([[x, y] for x in range(x) for y in range(y)])
```

above, whenever i use the iterator variable as x and y, *'its shows an error'*

but when i change it to a and b, *'it works fine'* see below

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
print([[a, b] for a in range(x) for b in range(y)]) #this is working fine
```

**Can anyone tell me the reason behind that `UnboundLocalError`?**

Comment: It seems unwise to use `x` for both the bound and the iteration variable of your range iterations. Similarly `y`. List comprehensions have a special internal scope, and you're trying to reference `x` and `y` and also assign to variables `x` and `y` with different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you're "redeclaring" `x` in your list comprehension. This is what happens in a micro scale of events:

1. `x = int(input())`. `x` is declared and assigned with user input.
2. `y = int(input())`. `y` is declared and assigned with user input.
3. `for x`. `x` is declared in a more local scope (inside the list comprehension), but not assigned.
4. `in range(x)`. The iteration is defined to occur within the result of `range(x)`. Since `x` is currently not assigned to any value, your `UnboundLocalError` exception happens.

As you have already seen, the solution is simply using a different variable for the iteration.